# How to manage the sites name for a django app when deployed?

Tags: django, configuration

I'm currently building a Django site that is in essence a type of content management system. However, the type of system is unimportant, but lets call it "CrappyPress - the crappy Django Wordpress-clone".

What I would like is for various people to be able to download the CrappyPress source and run their blogs. Which means that they need to be able to easily configure their site, such as the name of the blog, description, content for the front page, and lots of site-wide individual data.

So far I have come up with 2 approaches neither of which are suitable:

1. Put all the configuration information in a static configuration file, and have them edit this on the server - which isn't very user friendly.
2. Make a "site" object, have the user able to edit all of the information there, then restrict the site to having only 1 of these. The issue it this means there is an entry in the admin section, then the user has to go and open the site from the list of 'sites'. Again, not perfect UI-wise.

I've had a look at the ["sites framework"](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sites/) and this is more for managing multiple sites hosted through the same django server, which doesn't help me.

Additionally, for what its worth, I'm using South and Grappelli if that influences people.

**So how can I make it easy for an admin user to change site wide details of a django app, without odd proxy objects or having the user have to edit HTML or configuration files?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a whole set of apps which can help you save settings to the database called [live-settings](https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/live-setting/).

Comment: Thats pretty much straight what I was looking for, but I just didn't know the term. You rock, arocks!